# Automatically add all declared class variables to list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to automatically list all declared variables on my class. I am working on a pooling script, so for each gameobject I have a prefab, an array, an array size and a pool size. (they all follow naming standards, prefab name + "array" for array and etc).

```
private GameObject _PlayerLaserPrefab;
private GameObject[] _PlayerLaserPrefabArray;
private int _PlayerLaserPrefabPoolsize = 30;
private Queue<Transform> _PlayerLaserPrefabQueue = new Queue<Transform>();



private void Initiate_PlayerLaserPrefabPool()
{
    _PlayerLaserPrefabArray = new GameObject[_PlayerLaserPrefabPoolsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < _PlayerLaserPrefabPoolsize; i++)
    {
        _
    PlayerLaserPrefabArray[i] = Instantiate(_PlayerLaserPrefab,Vector3.zero, 
                                         Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Transform Obj=PlayerLaserPrefabArray[i].GetComponent<Transform>();
        ObjTransform1.parent = transform;
        _PlayerLaserPrefabQueue.Enqueue(ObjTransform1);
        _PlayerLaserPrefabArray[i].SetActive(false);

    }
}
```

this code has to be repeated for all game´s objects so I am looking for a method to dynamically generate these funcions and variables based on the object´s name.

//pseudo code would be:

```
foreach (gameobject in list)
create array
create queue
initiate pool
Generate spawn function
```

Comment: Why not use interfaces + generics, instead of trying to generate some code? Though if you really want to generate such code it's usually preferable to write a script that does it (outside of Unity)

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking for here.  Can you describe in a bit more detail the *actual problem* you're trying to solve, instead of describing your *proposed solution* and asking us how to make it work?  See also [What is the X Y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: As Unholy Sheep points out, I don't think you need code generation here.  What you're probably looking for is something akin to first-class functions, or maybe monkey patching.  There's almost certainly a simpler way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: You can build an interface with static members.